# to list files of a sub-directories in perl

Tags: perl

I need to search for directories  and store files present in the directory in an array (each directories constitute one array and I created hash of arrays). Apart from just files, a few directories may contain sub-directories and I need to list the files present in subdirectories into the same directory array. Here is the code I tried. It lists out files from directories along with sub directories. But it is unable to recognize sub-directories.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use File::Basename;

my %hash;
my @store;
my @list_of_dirs = grep { -d } glob "*";

print "LIST of DIRs = @list_of_dirs \n";

foreach my $dir (@list_of_dirs) {   
    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) { 
        next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
        print "FILE = $file\n";
        if ( -d $file) { print "IT IS A DIRECTORY\n"; }
            ## This statement is not getting printed though there are subdirectories 
            ## in some directories.
            push(@store, $file);      
        } #end_of_while
        print "$dir = @store \n";
       $hash{"$dir"} = [@store];
       @store = ();
} #end_of_foreach
print Dumper \%hash;
```

I also tried glob function but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Can anyone please have a look at my code and tell me what's wrong with this code.

```
while ( my $subdir = glob "$file/*" ) {
    my @sub_files = grep -f, glob "$subdir/*";
    print "SUBDIR $dir = @sub_files\n";
}
```

Comment: With your indentation fixed, I can spot a problem with your blocks, specifically a lack of a  `}`. Also, you are failing to take into account the relative path of the file to your cwd.

Comment: Also, you probably want a recursive method, like used in `File::Find` et al.

Comment: In fact there is no problem with `}`. I am trying to just print "IT IS A DIRECTORY\n"; to check if it can recognize sub-directories but this loop never gets executed though there are subdirectories inside some directories listed.

Comment: Yes, like I said, you need to take into account the relative path of the file to your cwd. If you are in `/user/foo`, and you open a dir `bar`, and you find a dir `baz` inside it, and you try to open `baz`, it will say "There is no such file", because it is looking for `/user/foo/baz`. You need to look for `bar/baz`

Comment: Yes, I saw it was me who removed the curly bracket when editing, I fixed that now.

Comment: Ah, understand. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: "_directories may contain sub-directories and I need to list the files preset in subdirectories into the same directory array_"  -- so you want only top-level directories in that hash, each with all files (including from its subdirectories)?  Example: your directory has five subdirectories -- you want your resulting hash to have five keys (those subdirectories), but each should have a list of _all_ files underneath (including their subdirs) ... correct?

Comment: @zdim Yes, exactly.

Comment: @nandeeshv "_Yes, exactly_" -- Thanks. Alright then, the main part of my answer does that

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are looking in one directory for filenames, but then trying to play with them in a different working directory.

`readdir` gives you only the name of the file. You can combine that with the directory name to get a path. This is explained in the docs for [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir):

```
opendir my $dh, $dir;

my $filename = readdir($dh);
my $path = catfile( $dir, $filename );
```

Alternately, you can change the current working directory to the directory you care about so that all files are in the current working directory:

```perl
chdir $dir;
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the file listings need also be recursive and that is not at all in the code shown in the question.  The `readdir` error has been explained, but to handle recursive traversal you should use a library instead. Here I use the very efficient core [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find).

In my understanding, files should be listed under only the top-level subdirectories, where each should include all files in the hierarchy underneath it, so from all of its subdirectories<sup>†</sup>

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dump qw(dd);
use Cwd qw(cwd);
use File::Find;

my $top_level = shift // cwd;

#say "Search from $top_level";

my @top_level_dirs = grep { -d } glob "$top_level/*";

say "Organize file list in top-level directories:";
say "\t$_" for @top_level_dirs;
say '';

my %tl_dir;
for my $dir (@top_level_dirs) { 
    find( sub {
        push @{$tl_dir{$dir}}, $File::Find::name if -f;
    },  
    $dir );
}

dd \%tl_dir;
```

This works for the directory given on the command line, or the current-working-directory. It invokes `find` for each top-level subdirectory so that code is trivial. Or one could run `find` once and inside distinguish top-level directories for which to organize/store filenames.

The `$File::Find::name` has the full path, while `$_` has only the filename.  Which to use is often a matter of choice but here you *need* the full path to distinguish files from subdirectories.

The code adds only regular files, by `-f`; if you'd rather to account for *all* files other than directories then change `if -f` to `if not -d`.  The subdirectories are shown in the full path for each file.

I use `Data::Dump` to show the data structure in the end but there are a number of other good libraries for that, `Data::Dumper` being in the core.

Since v5.20 instead of dereferncing with `@{ ... }` we can use [postfix dereference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax) syntax

```
push $tl_dir{$dir}->@*, $File::Find::name if -f;
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  If the files should be organized under their immediate directories then it's even simpler

```
my %dir;

find( sub {
    push @{$dir{$File::Find::dir}}, $File::Find::name if -f;
},  
$toplevel );
```